# "new" keyword causing red squiggle

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2013, f#-3.1

I wonder what's going on here...

I just created a new, empty F# Console application in Visual Studio 2013 (using F# 3.1 and .NET 4, FSharp.Core Version 4.3.1.0) and added the [Reactive Extensions Main Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Main/) using Nuget: `Install-Package Rx-Main`

Now check this out:

[image: Definition without new keyword]

This works and the hovering over test shows `val test: unit -> System.Reactive.Subjects.Subject<'a>`. As expected. Then I added the `new` keyword.

[image: Definition with new keyword]

Interesting. Does anybody know why adding the `new` keyword breaks the code? For reference, if you additionally specify the type parameter, it works:

[image: Definition with type parameters]

Comment: This can be demonstrated more easily by just defining a generic class `type MyClass<'a> () = do ()` and trying to instantiate it `let test = MyClass()` vs `let test = new MyClass()`.  No need for Rx or anything disposable.  Seems like a compiler idiosyncrasy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find a spec reference off-hand, but when using `new` explicit type args are required. You need to do:

```
let test() = new System.Reactive.Subjects.Subject<_>()
```

Comment: I tried finding the part of the specification that states this, but all I could come up with is [Section 6.4.2 - Object Construction Expressions](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.0/FSharpSpec-3.0-final.pdf), which does not say that the arguments have to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a static class, and static classes cannot be newed up.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.subjects.subject%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

And to elaborate on your specific error message, it means there is public no constructor available that accepts 0 parameters.  As far as I know, static classes only have private, parameterless constructors.

Comment: Wrong `Subject`. He's using this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229173(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: In the OPs examples, wouldn't he be using *both* classes based on the code snippets provided?  If not providing the type parameter, then the static class would have been used when attempting to new it up yes?

Comment: No. The compiler recognizes that this is an instantiation expression and infers the omitted type args (when `new` is not present).

Comment: Actually, @Kritner is right. :) The error message in the second picture refers to the static class. When I define a new generic class and try to instantiate it with `new`, the error message says: The type 'Test<_>' expects 1 type argument(s) but is given 0.